# Edit selected dropdown value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
Inserted Page:
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

From this option user select any one value and store it in db.

```
Edit page:

<select>
    ???
</select>
```

Now in edit page,display dropdown with selected value(what the user select fetch from db) and display other option in dropdown. What can I do??

Comment: you will need to run a query from the DB to get the value selected stored in the database & then have an if condition on each of the options - e.g if option 3 is true then that will be the selected="true" option

Comment: I need a explanation with code.Pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In Edit Page:

<select class="form-control" id="customer_id" name="customer_id">

    <?php foreach ( $customer as $cust ){?>

            <option value="<?php echo $datas[0]->customer_id; ?>"<?php if($cust->customer_id==$datas[0]->customer_id) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $cust->customer_id; ?></option>

    <?php }?>

</select>
```

In my code $datas[0]->customer_id contains db value(what user select from dropdown) and $customer contains all the dropdown value.So in edit page again you have all the dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set this way

$v_schedule is main table array
$v_employee is second table array

```
         <?php 

              foreach ($all_employee as $v_employee)
               {
               ?>
                 <option  <?php if($v_schedule->employee_id == 
                 $v_employee->employee_id ) echo "selected";?>  
                 value="<?php echo $v_employee->employee_id?>">
                <?php echo $v_employee->em_full_name;?> </option>

             <?php
               }
              ?>
```